# Tensorflow on Windows (DLL load failed and ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow (GPU) on Windows 10. I followed the instructions on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows.

During the installation process I have not noticed any issues but when I try to import tensorflow I get this error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-41389fad42b5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I am very new to this so any answers are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: After some research I tried a couple of things so I think I should mention them. Firstly, I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (Update 3). After this I re-installed CUDA toolkit 8.0 and cuDNN. I also checked the version of cuDNN which is v5.1 and I think is correct.  I also tried to pip install tensorflow-gpu but the issue is still not resolved. I have also tried the CPU version which works without any issue.

Edit 2: Ok so I managed to resolve the issue by using the cuDNN v6.0 despite what it says in the tensorflow website. I think it works now but I am not sure. I managed to run the 'Hello Tensorflow' example so I think it is ok now.

If anyone knows why this solution works I would appreciate the explanation.